# Connecting MS SQL Server to Netezza, for data import to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, import, odbc, netezza

I want to import data from Netezza to MS SQL Server. I tried lots of things and I couldn't reach to final step.

There are some [steps in this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)

The problem is about connection string:

```
Driver={any odbc driver's name};OdbcKey1=someValue;OdbcKey2=someValue;
```

Is there an example about `somevalue`?

Comment: `somevalue` depends on the relevant `OdbcKey` which vary with the `Driver`. That said, it's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to connect from MS SQL Server (as data consumer) to Netezza (as data source)? or from Netezza (as data consumer) to MS SQL Server (as data source)? (Your Microsoft link was truncated and cannot be followed.)

Comment: I am trying to connect from MS SQL to Netezza. Sorry for the link. The correct link is, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Comment: I've fixed the link in your question, as you should have done. If you're getting an error, you should provide this, and details of what you tried that brought that result. Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I found the solution. The problem is about my connection type. I was trying to copy the connection link from powerpivot connection, but it is an OLEDB connection and doesn't work for connect to Management Studio. I tried the connection string which is used for connecting excel directly from Netezza. It is an ODBC connection type and it worked for Management studio.